# Should potentially multicollinear variables be dropped

Tags: multicollinearity

I did correlation analysis for a set of variables and calculated the VIFs. For a couple of independent variables, the VIF is less than 4, however the correlation coefficient with other input variables is >0.7. Should I omit the variables based on the VIF / correlation coefficient?

Comment: Is there any meaning behind these independent variables?  If the underlying theory that you are working with is based on these variables I would keep them.  If you are doing model selection, I would just look at the performance of your model with and without the variables, take a look at the  residuals and see how well the model fits.  Also check the coefficients in your model to check for any tell-tale signs of multicollinearity such as large coefficients with alternating signs.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of different threshold values used for VIF - some workers are concerned at values as low as 4.0 (2.5 is the lowest I have seen - see http://statisticalhorizons.com/multicollinearity). So there are certainly researchers who would not consider your situation to be of concern.
Should you still think that the multicollinearity is a real problem in your case, it isn't necessary to go straight to dropping variables, for example, see this answer to a previous overlapping question: [Applying Generalized Linear Model to a data with high collinearity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80824/applying-generalized-linear-model-to-a-data-with-high-collinearity/80847#80847)